# Gee-haw whammy diddle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, coupled-oscillators

I was wondering if someone could please explain how a Gee-haw whammy diddle works. I have linked the Wikipedia page that does include an explanation that I don't completely understand, i.e. could you please give a fairly layman explanation as to how it works.

Also, I would appreciate if you could explain why you can change the direction of the spinning ect.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gee-haw_whammy_diddle

Comment: Have you ever tried spinning a hula hoop? Think about how that works, then re-read the Wikipedia page.